# Even numbers function in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Problem statement:

> Fill in the blanks to complete the “even_numbers” function. This function should return a space-separated string of all positive even numbers, excluding 0, up to and including the “maximum” variable that's passed into the function. Complete the for loop so that a function call like “even_numbers(6)” will return the numbers “2 4 6”.

My code:

```py
def even_numbers(maximum):

    return_string = "" # Initializes variable as a string

    for n in range(1, 11, 2):

    return return_string.strip()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've added _any_ logic related to the problem, so there is nothing to fix; just work for you to do

Comment: your for loop has a hardcoded 11. you should use the parameter `maximum` instead. Also, if you want even numbers why do you start at 1?

Comment: Couple issues:

 1. In Python, indentation is important; you need to indent the code inside the function.
 2. `range(1, 11, 2)` iterates over odd numbers, not even. Remember, `range(start, stop, step)` will generate numbers from `start` to `stop-1` with a step of `step`.

    - `start`: Starting value, inclusive.  
    - `stop`: Stopping value, exclusive.  
    - `step`: Increment between each number in the sequence.  

 3. The loop upper bound is hardcoded as `11`... you should utilize the `maximum` parameter.

 4.  You're not updating `return_string` inside the loop...

Comment: Try this:

`def even_numbers(maximum):
    return_string = ""
    for n in range(2, maximum + 1, 2):
        return_string += str(n) + " "
    return return_string.strip()`

 6.  (Optional) Appending to strings in Python is generally inefficient due to immutability, leading to `O(n)` time complexity for each append operation. Instead you'd want to accumulate strings in a list and then use `' '.join(your_list)` or `StringIO` from the `io` module for `O(n)` overall complexity.

Comment: I was about to... and then it got closed ***literally*** 10 secs before I did?

Comment: Because OP has shown no effort to do his/her homework.

Comment: `range(1, 11, 2):` is clearly their attempt since it is incorrect on multiple counts (using `1` and hardcoding `11`).

Comment: This question should not have been closed in my opinion. Try returning `" ".join(str(n) for n in range(2, maximum+1, 2))`

Answer (score 0):

The `range(start,end,step)` method gives you a series of numbers starting on `start` and ending just before `end`, increasing by `step` every time. It's usually used in for loops, since the for loop will just parse through those numbers in order, but the range method can be used on its own as well. Since the problem wants to start on `2` and wants to go up to and including `maximum`, you'll want `start` to be `2` and end to be `maximum+1`. If you want to use the for loop with the range method, you just need to add some code for it to do for each number it gives you (ie: adding the number to the end of `return_string`).